# Adding a file to a text message

Tags: sms

Have a Samsung galaxy 5 and I am trying to add a .pdf to a text message.
Have tried the drop box but it wouldn't let me attach the file
thanks,

dana

Answer (score 2):

With SMS (Short Message Service) you can only send text. The only way to share your pdf through this service is by pasting the Dropbox (or Google Drive or another cloud service) link where is stored your file. 
Otherwise you can always send an email :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to directly send anything other than an image or audio file through text message. The best thing to do would be to paste the public download link to the Dropbox file into the text message.